# Owl Carousel Slider Arrows positioning issue

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I have issue ( I think my code is not structured correctly ) with putting my owl carousel arrows exactly in the left and right side of my .container class. I am not sure how to structure it. Right Now it is working because I put them as position absolute but when I resize for small devices my left and right arrow looks so broken. I want to put them im my container which is 1200 px for desktop devices and I want to position them on the left and right side of the container. Here on the example my left and right controll arrows are missing and I do not have any clue why. I checked a lot of similar issues here and all of them are saying that I have to add my owl custom left and right controllers but when i do it via navText: [].... nothing shows on the screen here on the example.
Here is what I have until now. Any ideas ?

```js
// Owl Carousel Slider
$("#slider").owlCarousel({
  nav: true, // Show next and prev buttons
  dots: true,
  slideSpeed: 300,
  paginationSpeed: 400,
  items: 1,
  itemsDesktop: false,
  itemsDesktopSmall: false,
  itemsTablet: false,
  itemsMobile: false,
  navText: [
    '<a href="javascript:;" class="owl_next prev_owl"><img src="https://imgur.com/zTRFaaX" alt="left"></a>',
    '<a href="javascript:;" class="owl_prev next_owl"><img src="https://imgur.com/zTRFaaX" alt="left"></a>'
  ]
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
}

#slider .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.owl-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  z-index: 11;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.item div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  top: 60%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.owl-title,
.owl-caption {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.owl-text-slider-1 .owl-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.owl-text-slider-1 .owl-title:before {
  content: "";
  width: 52px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 4px;
}

.owl-caption {
  font-size: 51px;
  text-align: left;
}

.item .arrow-down {
  top: 85%;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
}

.prev_owl,
.next_owl {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.prev_owl {
  top: 50%;
  right: 18%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.next_owl {
  top: 50%;
  left: 18%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption .slider-content-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.trickcenter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css">
<div class="container">

  <div id="slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <div class="owl-text-slider-1">
          <h2 class="owl-title">Text 1</h2>
          <p class="owl-caption">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" title="Image" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <div class="owl-text-slider-1">
          <h2 class="owl-title">Text 1</h2>
          <p class="owl-caption">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <div class="owl-text-slider-1">
          <h2 class="owl-title">Text 1</h2>
          <p class="owl-caption">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <div class="owl-text-slider-1">
          <h2 class="owl-title">Text 1</h2>
          <p class="owl-caption">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <div class="owl-text-slider-1">
          <h2 class="owl-title">Text 1</h2>
          <p class="owl-caption">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <div class="owl-text-slider-1">
          <h2 class="owl-title">Text 1</h2>
          <p class="owl-caption">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #slider -->
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6n1jadp/)